# dynamically adding tabs

Tags: c#, winforms, tabs

I want to add tabs dynamically during the runtime.

I made a own class for the tabs like this:

```
namespace Demo
{
    public partial class Tabs : UserControl
    {
        private static DateTime ArrivalStart;
        public static DateTime arrivalStart
        {
            get { return ArrivalStart; }
            set { ArrivalStart = value; }

        }

        private static DateTime ArrivalEnd;
        public static DateTime arrivalEnd
        {
            get { return ArrivalEnd; }
            set { ArrivalEnd = value; }

        }

        private static DateTime DepartureStart;
        public static DateTime departureStart
        {
            get { return DepartureStart; }
            set { DepartureStart = value; }

        }

        private static DateTime DepartureEnd;
        public static DateTime departureEnd
        {
            get { return DepartureEnd; }
            set { DepartureEnd = value; }

        }

        public Tabs()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            LoadSubsidiaryXML();
            dtpArrivalStart.Format = DateTimePickerFormat.Custom;
            dtpArrivalStart.CustomFormat = "ddd dd MMM yyyy hh:mm";
            dtpArrivalEnd.Format = DateTimePickerFormat.Custom;
            dtpArrivalEnd.CustomFormat = "ddd dd MMM yyyy hh:mm";
            dtpDepartureStart.Format = DateTimePickerFormat.Custom;
            dtpDepartureStart.CustomFormat = "ddd dd MMM yyyy hh:mm";
            dtpDepartureEnd.Format = DateTimePickerFormat.Custom;
            dtpDepartureEnd.CustomFormat = "ddd dd MMM yyyy hh:mm";
        }

        private void LoadSubsidiaryXML()
        {
            XmlDocument subsidiary = new XmlDocument();
            subsidiary.Load("Subsidiaries.xml");

            XmlNodeList Subname = subsidiary.SelectNodes("subsidiaries/type/name");
            foreach (XmlNode name in Subname)
            {
                comboSubsidiaryTravel.Items.Add(name.InnerText);
            }
        }

        private void LoadWorkerXML(string xmlType)
        {
            comboWorkerType.Items.Clear();
            XmlDocument workerType = new XmlDocument();
            workerType.Load(xmlType);

            XmlNodeList worker = workerType.SelectNodes("worker/type/name");
            foreach (XmlNode name in worker)
            {
                comboWorkerType.Items.Add(name.InnerText);
            }
        }

         //Select XML which have to be populated to comboWorkerType
        private void chooseWorker()
        {
            string xmlType = "";
            string subsidiary = "";
            subsidiary = comboSubsidiaryTravel.Text;
            switch (subsidiary)
            {
                case "GH":
                    xmlType = "GHworkerType.xml";
                    LoadWorkerXML(xmlType);
                    break;

                case "GP":
                    xmlType = "GPworkerType.xml";
                    LoadWorkerXML(xmlType);
                    break;

                case "GN":
                    xmlType = "GNworkerType.xml";
                    LoadWorkerXML(xmlType);
                    break;

                case "GT":
                    xmlType = "GTworkerType.xml";
                    LoadWorkerXML(xmlType);
                    break;
                case "GS":
                    xmlType = "GSworkerType.xml";
                    LoadWorkerXML(xmlType);
                    break;

                case "GK":
                    xmlType = "GKworkerType.xml";
                    LoadWorkerXML(xmlType);
                    break;

                case "GBH":
                    xmlType = "GBHworkerType.xml";
                    LoadWorkerXML(xmlType);
                    break;

                case "GAS":
                    xmlType = "GASworkerType.xml";
                    LoadWorkerXML(xmlType);
                    break;

                case "Others":
                    comboWorkerType.Items.Clear();
                    break;
                default:
                    break;
            }
        }

        private void comboSubsidiaryTravel_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            chooseWorker();
        }

        private void dtpArrivalStart_ValueChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            ArrivalStart = dtpArrivalStart.Value;
            dtpArrivalEnd.MinDate = dtpArrivalStart.Value;
        }

        private void dtpArrivalEnd_ValueChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            ArrivalEnd = dtpArrivalEnd.Value;
            dtpDepartureStart.MinDate = dtpArrivalEnd.Value;
        }

        private void dtpDepartureStart_ValueChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            DepartureStart = dtpDepartureStart.Value;
            dtpDepartureEnd.MinDate = dtpDepartureStart.Value;
        }

        private void dtpDepartureEnd_ValueChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            DepartureEnd = dtpDepartureEnd.Value;
        }
    }
}
```

and I'm adding a new tab with a button:

```
private void btnAddWorker_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string title = "worker " + (tabsTravel.TabCount + 1).ToString();

            TabPage test = new TabPage();

            tabsTravel.TabPages.Add(test);
            test.Text = title;
            test.BackColor = Color.White;
            test.Controls.Add(new Tabs());

        }
```

Adding the tabs with the button and removing them with another button works fine, but now I got some Problems:

1. the comboWorkerType is depending on what is selected in the comboSubsidiaryTravel. but in all dynamically added tabs, the XML isn't loaded to the comboWorkerType if I selected an item in comboSubsidiaryTravel.
2. how can I access the dynamically added controls and their values like datetimepicker?

greetz

Tobi

EDIT:

this is the class where I'm using the values of the Datetimepicker:

```
namespace Demo
{
    class worker
    {
        public void ArrivalTimeSpan()
        {
            TimeSpan Arrival = new TimeSpan();

            Arrival = Page2.arrivalEnd - Page2.arrivalStart;
            System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show(Arrival.ToString());
        }

        public void DepartureTimeSpan() 
        {
            TimeSpan Departure = new TimeSpan();

            Departure = Page2.departureEnd - Page2.departureStart;
            System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show(Departure.ToString());
        }

        public void WorkTimeSpan() 
        {
            TimeSpan Work = new TimeSpan();

            Work = Page3.workEnd - Page3.workStart;
            System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show(Work.ToString());
        }
}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

A1: I do see eventhandler methods, but I do not see a line of code that actually connects the event to the eventhandler. E.g. comboSubsidiaryTravel.SelectedIndexChanged += comboSubsidiaryTravel_SelectedIndexChanged

A2: You can't directly. You have to check the Controls collection property to find them. Unless you are 'inside' the user control, then you can access them directly.

One major fundamental error I see though is the following: your DateTime variables in your user control are static! I'm pretty sure that is not what you want, you want normally instanced properties. How else are you going to keep the values separate?

Comment: first problem solved. thank you :-) but I don't really understand what you mean in your second answer. What do you mean by 'inside'? I made them static to access these DateTime-values accesible from another class where I want to calculate with these values. Isn't this the best way to make this?

Comment: @user1414157: `static` is not used in that sense..`static` used in C is different from how we use static in Object oriented world. If you want it to be accessible by other classes use access specier `public`..`static` will make it static - not dynamic.

Comment: Since you made them static this means that you do not have a value for each single user control. See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/79b3xss3(v=vs.80).aspx
You also made them public, which is enough to read them from another class.

Comment: so just deleting the static from this variables is enough?

Comment: Possibly, but I can't see how and where you hookup the events when a user changes a combo/datepicker.

Comment: after deleting, I got an error in the class where I work with these datetimepicker-values. For the non-static field, method or property Demo.Page2.arrivalEnd.get is needed a objectreference

Comment: I added the class to my question above

Comment: That sounds logical, since you need to specific user control object. You need to find that in the Controls collection of the form that the user control is on.

Comment: I'm confused. could you give me an example for this?